# Recursive function C?

Tags: c, recursion

Why does this recursive function work? I'm having trouble understanding why it doesn't keep calling itself until n=1 and then stop, not executing anything below where it calls itself.

```
int main(){
    int t[] = {7,9,6,4,2};
    int min, max;
    search_extremes_rec(t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]), &min, &max);
    printf("min: %d, max: %d", min, max);
    return 0;
}
void search_extremes_rec(const int t[], int n, int *min, int *max){
    if(n<=1){
        *min = t[0];
        *max = t[0];
    }else{
        search_extremes_rec(t, n-1, min, max);
        if(*min > t[n-1]){
            *min = t[n-1];
        }   
        else if(*max < t[n-1]){
            *max = t[n-1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually DOES keep calling itself until n=1. What is the problem ? I tried on onlinegdb

Comment: It does keep calling itself until n=1. Why do you assume otherwise?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The first two sentences are contradictory.

Comment: Based on "not executing anything below where it calls itself" it seems that you are expecting the recursive call to implicitly return. This is not the case, i.e., execution will continue from that point on after each recursive call returns, just like any other function call. (Follow the execution by stepping through it with a debugger and it should become clear.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to find out what a recursive function does, insert a couple of printouts.

```
void search_extremes_rec(const int t[], int n, int *min, int *max){
        printf("Entering search_extremes_rec. n:%d\n", n);
        if(n<=1){
                printf("Base case. Exiting\n");
                *min = t[0];
                *max = t[0];
        }else{
                printf("Calling recursively...\n");
                search_extremes_rec(t, n-1, min, max);
                printf("Recursive call done. n:%d min:%d max:%d\n", n, *min, *max);

                if(*min > t[n-1]){
                        *min = t[n-1];
                }
                else if(*max < t[n-1]){
                        *max = t[n-1];
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Entering search_extremes_rec. n:5
Calling recursively...
Entering search_extremes_rec. n:4
Calling recursively...
Entering search_extremes_rec. n:3
Calling recursively...
Entering search_extremes_rec. n:2
Calling recursively...
Entering search_extremes_rec. n:1
Base case. Exiting
Recursive call done. n:2 min:7 max:7
Recursive call done. n:3 min:7 max:9
Recursive call done. n:4 min:6 max:9
Recursive call done. n:5 min:4 max:9
min: 2, max: 9
```

As you can see, it does indeed continue until n=1.